# What should we do about question 16427?

Tags: discussion

As far as I see, [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/how-many-meanings-are-there-for-the-word-salaf) is a bit unclear and close to off-topic, I am not quite sure how to deal with it though.  In what way can it be edited to make it better / is it salvageable? if not, what actions should be taken on it?

Comment: unclear and too broad...